# targetting an access point with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables

I can target a client IP address on my router like:-

iptables -I INPUT -s 123.456.7.89 -j DROP

Is it possible to target the IP of the access point the client device is connecting through instead (or the SSID since each access point has it's own).

I've been looking at the match flag but can't find anything there. Thanks.

Comment: You need to filter packets by their destination mac-address. but this field will available, after routing(POSTROUTING) .

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to filter by mac address, but it's not so easy.

Please spend some times with this picture:

[image]

**Using the MAC module extension for iptables** from [here](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section9)

> The side effect explained here occurs when the netfilter code is
>   enabled in the kernel, the IP packet is routed and the out device for
>   that packet is a logical bridge device. The side effect is encountered
>   when filtering on the MAC source in the iptables FORWARD chains.
>
> As should be clear from earlier sections, the traversal of the
>   iptables FORWARD chains is postponed until the packet is in the bridge
>   code. This is done so we can filter on the bridge port out device.
>   This has a side effect on the MAC source address, because the IP code
>   will have changed the MAC source address to the MAC address of the
>   bridge device.
>
> It is therefore impossible, in the iptables FORWARD chains, to filter
>   on the MAC source address of the computer sending the packet in
>   question to the bridge/router. If you really need to filter on this
>   MAC source address, you should do it in the nat PREROUTING chain.
>   Agreed, very ugly, but making it possible to filter on the real MAC
>   source address in the FORWARD chains would involve a very dirty hack
>   and is probably not worth it.

Comment: struggling with this -- iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source MA:CA:DD:RE:SS -j DROP -- I get error 'couldn't find match mac'